# 3$\times$3 and 2$\times$2 matrices that satisfy $A^2 = -I$, $I$ being the identity matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for all square matrices $A$ of order 2 and 3 that satisfy $A^2 = - I$, $I$ being the identity matrix of the corresponding order.

Comment: What types of numbers are allowed in the entries?

Comment: No restrictions are placed on the entries.

Comment: @user130354 I think vadim123 is asking whether your matrices have real entries or complex entries.  "No restrictions" might still mean "any real number" in some contexts.

Comment: Lets say I want all entries to be real, no imaginary entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with real entries that satisfies the equation $A^2=-I$.  Suppose there were.  We take determinants, to get $$\left\lvert A\right\rvert^2=\left\lvert A^2\right\rvert=\left\lvert -I\right\rvert=-1$$
But $\left\lvert A\right\rvert$ is real, and no real number squares to $-1$.

In the $2\times 2$ case, by a similar argument we must have $\left\lvert A\right\rvert=\pm1$.  There are solutions, e.g. $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.  To find them all use @Mitch Hughes' approach (which has been, unfortunately, deleted).  To summarize, calculate a system of equations from $$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)^2=-I$$

Comment: In the $2\times2$ case, you have $\left\lvert A\right\rvert^2=1$, so maybe $\left\lvert A\right\rvert=1$ and maybe $\left\lvert A\right\rvert=-1$. Is there a quick way to rule out $\left\lvert A\right\rvert=-1$?

Comment: Good point, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

@vadmin answers your question for $3\times3$ matrices. For $2\times2$ matrices, either:

- There is at least one real eigenvalue. So there is a subspace of dimension at least $1$, where $A$ acts as scaling by $\lambda$. So $A^2$ acts as scaling by $\lambda^2\geq0$. This is not compatible with $A^2$ being $-I$, since $-I$ scales by $-1$ in all directions.
- Two complex conjugate eigenvalues: first you can factor out some $cI$ so that $A=(cI)B$ with $\left\lvert B\right\rvert=1$. Now $B$ has two complex conjugate eigenvalues each with magnitude $1$. There is a basis in which $B$ is simply a rotation matrix by some angle $\theta$. Note that $-I$ is rotation by $\pi$ about the origin. To have $A^2=-I$, you need $c^2B^2$ to be rotation by $\pi$. So you need $c=\pm1$ and $B$ to be a rotation by $\pi/2$.

So the solutions to this issue are 
$$\begin{align}
A&=\pm P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\pi/2)&-\sin(\pi/2)\\\sin(\pi/2)&\cos(\pi/2)\end{bmatrix}P\\
&=\pm P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}P
\end{align}$$
where $P$ can be any invertible matrix. ($P$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the one where $B$ is a rotation). If you want to spell it out by entries, then let $a,b,c,d$ be any four numbers with $ad-bc\neq0$. Then you have $$\begin{align}
A
&=\pm\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\frac{\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}}{ad-bc}\\
&=\frac{\pm1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c&-a\\d&-b
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac{\pm1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}ac+bd&-a^2-b^2\\c^2+d^2&-ac-bd\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The initial arguments are unnecessarily complicated: any eigenvalue$~\lambda$ of a matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2+I=0$ must satisfy $\lambda^2+1=0$, so $\def\i{\mathbf i}\lambda\in\{\i,-\i\}$. Also I don't think it is customary to extend the notion of being a rotation matrix (which needs to be orthogonal) to being a matrix similar to a rotation matrix (which doesn't), so you should be more careful than saying that $B$ is a rotation by $\pi/2$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It looks like you posted this comment at the same time I was trimming it down. But I still stand by those first two bullets which are now gone. $2\times2$ matrices are categorized in these three categories geometrically (corresponding to how the characteristic polynomial factors) and understanding those geometric categorizations let me see the solution for $2\times2$ fast, even if it took a bit longer to write. As for the second part of your comment, I said "There is a basis in which $B$..."

Comment: I think I was commenting on the bullet points as I still see them now. The second one ends "[you need]  $B$ to be a rotation by $\pi/2$"; that was the sentence I was referring to.

Answer (score -3):

There are essentially infinite solutions that satisfy A^2 = -I for 2x2 and 3x3 matrices.

They can be solved in similar manners of creating systems of equations and then solving those to produce general solutions. I will solve for 2x2 matrices. 
For standard square matrices we have a matrix A such that

A =\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}

by multiplying the matrix by itself, we get the following matrix

A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}a^2+bc&ab+bd\\ac+cd&bc+d^2\end{bmatrix}

so we have the following set of conditions that we must statisfy:

1. a^2+bc = -1
2. b(a+d) = 0
3. c(a+d) = 0
4. d^2 + bc = -1

By solving this system we will be able to see that conditions that a,b,c and d must satisfy

We will first begin by subtracting the first and last equations to get:

a^2-d^2 = 0

so therefore, we can see that a = +/- d

We will first explore the first case when a = d

We immediately see through the 2nd and 3 equations that b and c must equal 0 since a+d will never be 0, unless a = d = 0 (discussed later)

However, knowing that b=c=0, we see that that the 1st and 4th equations will never hold true since a^2 and d^2 will be positive, but it must equal -1.

Now we explore the case when a = -d

Say that a = an arbitrary constant t (then d = -t)

Through the 2nd and 3rd equation we see that c and d could essentially be anything too, since a+d = 0 and the equation would always be true.
Thus the only condition it needs to satisfy are:

bc + t^2 = -1 (since a^2 = d^2 = t^2)

so bc = -(1+t^2)

Now we pick another arbitrary constant s for c

so b = -(1+t^2)/s

As a result we have the following conditions for a,b,c, and d that satisfy A^2 = -I

- a= t
- b= -(1+t^2)/s
- c= s
- d= -t

which can also be written as:

A =\begin{bmatrix}t&-(1+t^2)/s\\s&-t\end{bmatrix}

for any values t and s (notice that case of a=d=0 is included here)

As a result, there are infinite a,b,c,d that satisfy A^2 = -I that all lie on a plane in space (since geometric multiplicity of 2)

Comment: There are _no_ $3\times3$ matrices for which this can be done.